# Зачем в Java создавать самого себя из static main()?

Tags: java

При решении оллимпиадных задач, и не только, люди часто в методе main создают объект этого же класса, и запускают его уже нестатический метод run.

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        //code here
    }
}
```

[Пример из acm.timus.org FAQ](http://acm.timus.ru/help.aspx?topic=java)

Зачем так делать, если можно просто помечать все члены как static?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если реализовывать *Runnable*, то в предыдущих версиях Java это был единственный способ отхапать себе большой стек и сделать возможным, скажем, глубокую рекурсию.

А так это банально удобнее -- везде писать **static** не только лениво, но и несимпатично. В том коде, что вы привели одна строчка кода и один лишний метод заменяет тысячи **static**'ов.

Я лично, использую не один *run*, а методы *init*, *solve*, *finish*, где в *init*'е объявляю ввод и вывод, в *finish*'е делаю flush для output-потока, а в *solve* просто пишу решение задачи. Таким образом, с помощью шаблонов в вашей любимой IDE вы можете сделать удобный шаблон таким образом, что всю эту стандартную рутину(ввод-вывод) не писать тысячу раз, а IDE сама генерировала код, а вы только писали решение в *solve*.

to Dex: кто мешает просто сделать метод *run*, для этого не обязательно реализовывать *Runnable* :)

Comment: Да да, сперва написал, потом подумал. Но вы, мне кажется, описали все несколько запутанно. Дело в том, что обращаться из статической функции можно только к статическим полям и функциям класса. Или же создавать себя же, как объект и работать с собой и со всеми своими полями и методами, как нужно.

Comment: Ну человек вроде понимает разницу между static и не static, зачем об этом говорить тогда. Как я понял вопрос заключался в "Зачем все делают так, если можно так" и говорилось конкретно про олимпиадное программирование. Я объяснил свою мотивацию делать именно через создание объекта.

Comment: хм, прикольно, а если еще и fluent интерфейсы прикрутить, то можно будет писать new A().init().solve().finish(); :)

Comment: "Если реализовывать Runnable, то в предыдущих версиях Java это был единственный способ отхапать себе большой стек" -  это вы тут что-то странное пишите. Факт реализации классом какого бы то ни было интерфейса не влияет и не влиял на величину стека. Возможно, речь шла о создании потока с Runnable в виде Main.

Comment: я именно это и имел ввиду.